# Is this question about game dynamics on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I have a question, but before I ask it, I want to make sure its on topic for this site.
Is the following question acceptable for this site? If not, is there a way I can change it to make it acceptable?

> Seth Priebatsch recently gave a
>   tedtalk entitled “[Building the game
>   layer on top of the world.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yn9fTc_WMbo)” In it,
>   Seth described four “game dynamics,”
>   techniques used by game designers to
>   make games fun and addictive. The four
>   dynamics that Priebtsch described
>   were:
>
> 1. Appointment dynamic-a dynamic in which to succeed, one must return at a
>      predefined time to take a
>      predetermined action. (Real life
>      example: happy hour)
> 2. Influence and status-the ability of one player to modify the behavior
>      of another's actions through social
>      pressure. (Example: different color
>      credit cards as a reflection of
>      status)
> 3. Progression dynamic-a dynamic in which success is granularly displayed
>      and measured through the process of
>      completing itemized tasks. (Example:
>      linkedin profile progress bar)
> 4. Communal discovery-a dynamic wherein an entire community is rallied
>      to work together to solve a challenge.
>      (Example: finding interesting content
>      on Digg)
>
> Seth explained these four game
>   dynamics in his talk and added that
>   his company has an additional three.
>   I'm curious if anyone has any guesses
>   about what those other three game
>   dynamics might be.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, here's the question: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3131/what-are-the-other-three-game-dynamics

Answer (score 2):

It's about making games fun, therefore it's about game design, therefore it's about game development, therefore it's on-topic.

I figure pretty much anything game-specific that happens before the game is released is on-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

Question seems totally on topic to me. Broad Game design questions are cool here, and that seems like an answerable question as well.